Doubts on the procedure: convexity of a function
I'm writing here to ask for clarifications about my professor's solution of this exercise: state if $f(x, y) = \ln(x^a - y)$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $a \in (0, 1)$.
Now he says that for $f$ to be convex it's necessary that the level set $\{(x, y) : f(x, y) \leq k\}$ where $k \geq 0$ has to be convex for every $k$.

Here I have also doubts, because I think of the function $-x^2-y^2$ and its level sets are convex, though that function is concave. Did I understand bad, or is this example bad?

Anyway, he then proceeds in calculation: $\ln(x^a-y) \leq k \implies x^a \leq y + e^k$.
By choosing the point $(0, 0)$ then $0 \leq e^k$ always true.
By choosing the point $(2, 2^a)$ then $2^a \leq 2^a + e^k$ always true.
Yet the medium point $(1, 2^{a-1})$ makes the inequality true? $1 \leq 2^{a-1} + e^k$, he then says yes since $a \in (0, 1)$.
But how? If I choose $k = \frac{1}{100}$, this inequality is surely wrong.
Can you please explain me if I missed something or where I'm wrong/he's wrong?
Thank you!
P.s. We are, for the moment, forbidden to use Hessian matrix to study convexity. We are allowed to use methods like the one above (?), restrictions or the analytic definition.
EDIT
Anyway, how can the function be convex on $\mathbb{R}^2$? First of all it's not even entirely defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, and also for $a \in (0, 1)$ I can see that $\ln(x^a -y)$ is composition between $\ln(x)$ and $x^a - y$. The latter is concave since it's sum of concave. The first is concave increasing, hence the composition is concave...

Note that the relevant level sets are defined with a $\leq$, not a $\geq$. So the level sets of $-x^2 -y^2$ are of the entire plane $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus C$ excluding a disk $C$, i.e. not convex sets.

Suppose $x_i^a \leq y_i + e^k$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Note also that $g(x) = x^a$, $0 < a < 1$, is a concave function. Then, with $\lambda_i\geq 0$, $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$ and using the concavity of $g(x)$, $(\sum_i \lambda_i x_i)^a \leq \lambda_i x_i^a \leq \lambda_i y_i + e^k$. This shows that if all $(x_i,y_i)$ are in the level set, so is $(\sum_i \lambda_i x_i, \sum_j \lambda_j y_j)$, i.e. the level set is convex. I think what you missed is that $k > 0$ and therefore $e^k > 1$.

@ErikT You're right, I really missed that for $k > 0$, $e^k > 1$. Subtle but perfect. Thank you! You may want to write that comment as an answer, I would accept it

@ErikT Anyway, how can the function be convex on $\mathbb{R}^2$? First of all it's not even entirely defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, and also for $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ I can see that $\ln(x^a -y)$ is composition between $\ln(x)$ and $x^a - y$. The latter is concave since it's sum of concave. The first is concave increasing, hence the composition is concave...

Wrote an answer with some more point. Note the updated diagnosis of your example. It indeed works as I said for $k=1/100$, but nothing prevents you from picking $k=-100$ instead so it needs a better diagnosis.

A few comments first:

Regarding your EDIT: In convex analysis it is common to reinterpret a function $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$, with $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, to an extended function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm\infty\}$. The convention is that $f(\mathbf{x}) = +\infty$ for $\mathbf{x} \notin D$ outside the domain, at least for convex $f$. Additionally, this requires some conventions for arithmetic involving $\infty$. (Whether this is relevant for what your professor was doing I don't know.)

A function is convex if (a) it's domain is convex, and (b) it is always below the linear interpolation i.e. $f(\lambda\mathbf{x}_1 + (1-\lambda) \mathbf{x}_2) \leq \lambda f(\mathbf{x}_1) + (1-\lambda) f(\mathbf{x}_2)$ for all $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2 \in D$ and all $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Your function $f(x,y) = \ln(x^a - y)$ is at the outset well-defined for $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^a > y\}$. The domain $D$ is convex. The quickest way to see the convexity of $D$ is that $x^a > y$, with $a \in (0,1)$, is the region below a concave function---that region is convex. So part (a) of the definition is satisfied. Part (b) of the definition is not satisfied. For example, for a fixed $x_0$ the function $g(y) = \ln(x_0^a - y)$ is concave in the same way that $\ln(y)$ is concave. So your function is not convex.

An equivalent test for convexity is that the epigraph is a convex set. This is a necessary and sufficient condition. For a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the epigraph is $(n+1)$-dimensional set $\{(\mathbf{x},z) | z \geq f(\mathbf{x})\}$ is a convex set. In your case, the epigraph is the 3-dimensional $\{(x,y,z) | z \geq \ln(x^a-y)\}$.

A necessary, but not sufficient, condition for your function to be convex is that every level set of the form $C = \{(x,y) | \ln(x^a - y) \leq k\}$ is a convex set. Note that this is a 2-dimensional set, unlike the 3-dimensional epigraph. Your function, although it is non-convex, satisfies this condition. This can be seen as follows:


Suppose $(x_i,y_i) \in C$, which as you note is equivalent to $x_i^a \leq y_i + e^k$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Note also that $g(x) = x^a$, $0 < a < 1$, is a concave function. Then, with $\lambda_i\geq 0$, $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$ and using the concavity of $g(x)$, $(\sum_i \lambda_i x_i)^a \leq \lambda_i x_i^a \leq \lambda_i y_i + e^k$. This shows that if all $(x_i,y_i)$ are in the level set, so is $(\sum_i \lambda_i x_i, \sum_j \lambda_j y_j)$, i.e. the level set is convex.

What goes wrong with your counterexample? Well, $(x,y) = (0,0)$ is not in the domain $D$, and if we assign a value it is $f(0,0) = -\infty$. Same with $(x,y) = (2,2^a)$.


Thank you so much for this detailed answer. Just to be really sure: in my edit, did I do well? I mean about the compositions and so on, I found it's concave in $(0, +\infty)^2$

Yes, you're right that the function is concave on $D = {(x,y) | x^a

y > 0}$ and you can extend the domain to $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}+ \times \mathbb{R}+$ by assigning $-\infty$ outside of $D$.

